# How to resolve spring-boot-starter-mail:3.0.6 dependency vulnerabilities?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, cve

My project is importing:
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:3.0.6'

My SonarQube OWASP Dependency Scan is reporting vulnerabilities:

app.jar: jakarta.mail-1.0.0.jar (shaded: org.eclipse.angus:angus-core:1.0.0)        pkg:maven/org.eclipse.angus/angus-core@1.0.0    HIGH    1       9

app.jar: jakarta.mail-1.0.0.jar (shaded: org.eclipse.angus:angus-mail:1.0.0)        pkg:maven/org.eclipse.angus/angus-mail@1.0.0    HIGH    1       9
app.jar: nimbus-jose-jwt-9.22.jar (shaded: net.minidev:json-smart:2.4.8)    cpe:2.3:a:json-

smart_project:json-smart:2.4.8:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:json-smart_project:json-smart-v2:2.4.8:*:*:*:*:*:*:*  pkg:maven/net.minidev/json-smart@2.4.8  HIGH    1   High    31

The CVE for these:
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44549
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-1370

https://ossindex.sonatype.org/component/pkg:maven/org.eclipse.angus/angus-mail@1.0.0?utm_source=dependency-check&utm_medium=integration&utm_content=8.2.1

Possible to exclude org.eclipse.angus:angus-mail ?

How can I resolve these?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you continue your cartoon and do not remove the module from the project.
If such a problem existed, this point would be written in the [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.angus/jakarta.mail/1.0.0). But now there is no such thing in maven repository of this project.
Also if you see the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-mail) of Spring boot starter mail, there is a dependency of `org.eclipse.angus:jakarta.mail` in the code, but there is no vulnerability report in the maven repository.
Also you can follow vulnerability reports of spring boot [here](https://security.snyk.io/package/maven/org.springframework.boot:spring-boot/3.0.6)